# Resampling netcdf file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, netcdf, zonal-statistics, resampling

What is the best way to change the cell size of a netcdf file, keeping it as netcdf?

I have looked into ArcGIS and GDAL and have not found anything yet. I prefer to use python if a solution is available.

The netcdf file is CRU monthly rainfall data, which I am running zonal statistics on to get mean value for districts in Malawi. Because the cell size is large, districts are showing up as having no data. This makes sense because the center of the cell is not located within the polygon districts with no data. My goal is to change the resolution from ~60km2 to ~10km2 which should pick up the cell values in the districts when I do zonal stats.

Comment: Is a Python (numpy/scipy) solution OK? Is the grid regularly-shaped?

Comment: Have you seen this [Q&A](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177168/resampling-netcdf-file)?

Comment: @RichardLaw, yes a python numpy/scipy solution would be great! Yes, the grid is regularly shaped.

Comment: @Hornbydd, Yes, I have seen this. But only a GDAL command line option was discussed and his last question was not answered.

Comment: This may help: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html